# how to secure cookies in play framework?

Tags: scala, cookies, playframework, session-cookies, playframework-2.2

I am facing a cookies problem in my website , I am using Scala with Play Framework 2.2.0.
If user replaces cookies with another user's cookies it works there i want to stop that please give me any solution.I have changed and modify in application.conf file with all security but i did not get any effect in my application.
If there is any type of trick or logic behind it please tell me.

Comment: The advice in [the Play CSRF documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaCsrf) is correct and will protect against simple cookie-replacement attempts; make sure you add the `CSRFFilter` to your `Global` as directed and you should be protected against these types of attacks.

Comment: thank you for giving me solution. Please tell me how can i implement it with cookies. Is it only way to secure cookies? thank you for giving me an idea to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the documentation it is just a config change https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/SettingsSession.

Note: problems with deserialization might occur.